# Cannot uninstall git - git clone broken

Tags: macos, homebrew, sudo, git

I cannot clone any repository on my mac anymore. I don't know since when exactly it got broken.

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myrep.git
Cloning into 'myrep'...
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The thing is my ssh id_rsa key is still the same. I recreated it anyway, updated it in my `BitBucket` account's ssh keys, and the same error shows up when I try to clone my repository. I tried the very same procedure on another machine (redhat) and git clone worked. So there is something happening with my version of git.

I thought about reinstalling git. So I first tried uninstalling it:

```
$ brew uninstall git
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.9.0... (1,424 files, 31.3M)
```

but it seems to be several versions of git installed:

```
$ git
# displays the usage here

$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

So I retried using this version:

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myrep.git
Cloning into 'myrep'...
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Still not working. I tried removing those git files:

```
$ rm -f /usr/bin/git*
rm: /usr/bin/git: Operation not permitted
rm: /usr/bin/git-cvsserver: Operation not permitted
rm: /usr/bin/git-receive-pack: Operation not permitted
rm: /usr/bin/git-shell: Operation not permitted
rm: /usr/bin/git-upload-archive: Operation not permitted
rm: /usr/bin/git-upload-pack: Operation not permitted

$ sudo rm -f /usr/bin/git*
Password:
rm: /usr/bin/git: Operation not permitted
rm: /usr/bin/git-cvsserver: Operation not permitted
rm: /usr/bin/git-receive-pack: Operation not permitted
rm: /usr/bin/git-shell: Operation not permitted
rm: /usr/bin/git-upload-archive: Operation not permitted
rm: /usr/bin/git-upload-pack: Operation not permitted
```

Even with sudo I cannot remove them, why? Do you think my git clone issue might come from that? I have no idea what to do anymore. I need to use git on that computer so badly I have been very stuck.

```
$ ls -a /usr/bin/git
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    18K May  5 08:05 /usr/bin/git*
```

Comment: It's a very bad idea to attempt removing stuff from `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It wasn't obvious to me but itwas about global configuration. I played a bit with the command `git config --global` which set a hidden git config file in my home folder. There was the information regarding another remote I set back then. This remote pointed to a repository which I deleted so git clone tried to fetch information from that deleted repo first. I just deleted that git global configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` to check connection to Bitbucket.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html#TroubleshootSSHIssues-ssh-Tconnectiontest(GitBash/MacOSX/Linux)